# Piwik iframe displaying multiple tab instead of showing analytics of website

Tags: magento-1.9, phtml

I have installed piwik in ubuntu and then i have installed Piwik Ecommerce from magento connect. Piwik is running on sever, but piwik iframe is not displaying any results in magento backend.

Reports->PiwikIframe displaying multiple tabs, and not giving any information. I have also added the following line in config/config.ini.php under general tab:

enable_framed_pages=1

[image]

Comment: This cannot be resolved here - please check with the maintainers of the extension.